# How to find the residue of $\frac1{z}(z+\frac 1 z)^{24}$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the question it is hinted to use the binomial expansion to find the constant term.  But I am unsure how to go about this

Comment: This is $\frac1{z^{25}}(z^2+1)^{24}$. The change of variable $t=z^2$ shows that the $\frac1z$ term corresponds to the $t^{12}$ term in $(t+1)^{24}$, hence it is ${24\choose12}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By the binomial expansion, 
$$\frac1{z}\left(z+\frac 1 z\right)^{24}=
z^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k}\cdot z^{k}(z^{-1})^{24-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k}z^{k-(24-k)-1}.$$
What is the residue at $z=0$, i.e. the coefficient of $z^{-1}$?